# How to obtain term symbols for an excited electronic configuration?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, spectroscopy

I have trouble writing down the term symbols for the first excited state of Neon, $\ 1s^22s^22p^53s^1$. I thought it would be $\ ^3P_2$, but the correct answer is $\ ^1P_1$ and I cannot understand why.

Comment: I've tried to find my own configuration, but it is identical to the one you propose. Where does this example come from?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry to answer late. The example came from an old university exam. However, I remembered that my error was not considering the rule that prohibits transitions between configurations of different spin.